# Jquery .animate() not working with cached (global) divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, jquery-animate

I'm fairly new to Jquery so please let me know if there are any mistakes in display - I've tried to make at as reader friendly as possible. I also appologize ahead of time if this question ends up being terribly simple.

I am caching my main div ids as global elements to call back on. However when I try and animate them, the animations do not fire. If I don't cache my divs, the animations work just fine - but I call each one multiple times and would like to cache them for speed.

Here's a snippet of my code below as an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $itCon = $('#it_container'),
         $webCon = $('#web_container'),
         $custCon = $('#custom_container');
         $lowCon = $('#low_container');

    $itCon.on('click', function(){
        if ($lowCon.css('display') == 'none') {
            $custCon.animate({
                 left: '12%'
                }, 600, 'easeOutQuad', function() {
                     $('#custom_container').fadeToggle(100)
                });
            $webCon.delay(500)
                .queue(function(next){
                    $(this).animate({
                        left: '45%'
                        }, 1200, 'easeOutQuad', function(){
                             $webCon.fadeToggle(100)});
                    next()});
            $lowCon.delay(1901)
                 .queue(function(next){$(this).fadeToggle(400)
                 .animate({'top': '0%'
                       }, 1000, function(){}); 
                    next()});        
        } else {
            $lowCon.animate({'top': '0%'
                       }, 1000, function(){}); 
                    next()});
            $webCon.delay(1001)
                .queue(function(next){
                    $(this).fadeToggle(400)
                        .animate({left: '0%'
                                 }, 1500, 'swing', function(){});
                        next()});
            $custCon.delay(1001)
            .queue(function(next){
                $(this).fadeToggle(400)
                    .animate({left: '0%'
                             }, 1500, 'swing', function(){});
                    next()});
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for this?

Comment: Sure give me a moment...

Comment: in your fiddle ,u missing close function tag `);` ,just comment u

Comment: Thanks, the ); have been added.

Comment: I am sorry but I am failing to understand what you are _really_ trying to achieve here. Do you expect your `if` block to execute? Because currently it seems, only your `else` block executes. Again, I could be wrong but please help me understand.

Comment: Well, on my actual page, I have several different div elements that will execute an animation (i.e. move left, up, down, etc), and then fade out when another div element is clicked on. When the element that was originally clicked on is clicked on a second time, the other div elements will fade back in and animate to their original position. Make sense?

Comment: It does but what currently seems to be the problem though?

Comment: The problem is that the .animate() will not fire (i.e. .animate({left: '12%}, 1000)) if I use the global variables. The delay() and fadeToggle() work just fine, but the div animations will not work. If I do not use the global variables i.e. $webCon and use the actual element instead i.e. $('web_container') the animations fire just fine. At this point I am just confounded why the animations will not fire, as the  code looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $itCon = $('#it_container'),
        $webCon = $('#web_container'),
        $custCon = $('#custom_container');


    $itCon.on('click', function(){
        if ($itCon.css('display') == 'none') {
            $custCon.animate({
                left: '12%'
                }, 600, 'easeOutQuad', function() {
                    $('#custom_container').fadeToggle(100)
                });
            $webCon.delay(500)
                .queue(function(next){
                    $(this).animate({
                        left: '45%'
                        }, 1200, 'easeOutQuad', function(){
                            $webCon.fadeToggle(100)});
                    next()});
        } else {
            $webCon.delay(1001)
                .queue(function(next){
                    $(this).fadeToggle(400)
                        .animate({left: '0%'
                                 }, 1500, 'swing', function(){});
                        next()});
            $custCon.delay(1001)
            .queue(function(next){
                $(this).fadeToggle(400)
                    .animate({left: '0%'
                             }, 1500, 'swing', function(){});
                    next()});
        }
    });
 });
```

What actually happend is because of this lines:

```
var $itCon = $('#it_container'),
    $webCon = $('#web_container'),
    $custCon = $('#custom_container'),
```

You need to change it to this:

```
var $itCon = $('#it_container'),
    $webCon = $('#web_container'),
    $custCon = $('#custom_container');
```

The bug occur because instead of using the $itCon you are declaring it again with an onclick event. You need to be careful in using semicolon and colon because they have a big differences.

And also in your code you need to change the 2 curly braces at the end to:

```
   });
});
```

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/8nLexkn5/2/

Comment: Neil, thank you for the answer, but in the fiddle you provided I still only see the fadeToggle working - the animations are not working...are the animations working for you?

Comment: yes it is working. you just need to wait a moment for that

Comment: I think your code is fine. Though needs a little fix.

Comment: In my actual code I have had the correct semicollon and simply made the typo when copying it over, but I still am not getting the animations to fire even with the addition of console.log('clicked'). Only the fadeToggle() and .delay() will work

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle? Does it work? What browser are you using?

Comment: Please note this is very crucial you need to change the 2 curly braces at the end as what I provided on my answer. If not corrected your js code will not work.

Comment: Yes I did change the curly braces - thank you for the catch. I have tried both Chrome and Firefox, with no luck on the .animate() portions of the code for either the fiddle or my localhost...